# SMS Triggered Sends for Long Code Support with multiple countries sms triggered SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobileconnect, sms

I have a long code that is provisioned for nultiple countries however the locale of the long code shows up in my account as GB. When I try sending to different countries i successfully get a token ID but messages are not sent. Is this even feasible? Locale for long Code is GB. Long code is provisioned for multiple countries. Send SMS triggered message below
Subscribers[
Mobile Number 44...,
Mobile Number 1317....

Comment: GB long code is typically used to send to multiple countries, how are. you sending, and is the phone number opted in?

Comment: Yes, so I added the optin equals true and it is now working . Thanks